# Resource-tracking libraries for Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, resources, open-source, resource-timing-api

I want to build a simple task scheduler on a Ubuntu cluster, so I need a resource-tracking library that exposes an API for other user-level applications.

I have been searching for a while, but all I found are command-line tools.

So I'm wondering if there is any usable resource-tracking libraries for Ubuntu Linux?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
cpu: /proc/stat
memory: /proc/meminfo
network io: /proc/net/dev or /sys/class/net/<dev>/statistics/
block io: /proc/diskstats or /sys/block/<dev>/stat
block space (in the sense of mounted filesystem): df (-a)
```

Also look at /sys/fs/cgroup/. It may help :)